# Good encryption software(preferably free) that doesn't require data reallocation?

Tags: security, truecrypt

I recently started messing around with encryption software, and TrueCrypt was my first choice. I however found out it has an inconvenient problem: it requires the files to be actually moved to the disk in order for the protection to take place. Is there a software that encrypts the files in-place and maps them to the new drive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're meaning. TrueCrypt supports encrypted volumes and containers that can be stored on unencrypted volumes. To store encrypted files on them (or gain access to them unencrypted), it mounts these volumes/files to a drive letter in Windows, and the encryption/decryption occurs transparently.

Comment: What are your actual requirements? How is moving files inconvenient for you?

Comment: I mean that mounting the files to an encrypted drive letter requires said files to be moved instead of copied; I tried accessing copied files without mounting the driver and they worked normally. Moving would be inconvenient because I plan on encrypting files that are part of certain programs, and not the programs as a whole(not sure if I was clear).

Comment: @Victor - Bitlocker is free.  TrueCrypt and Bitlocker are pretty much your only good options for encrypting volumes.